# How can I output TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(started_at, month) as string, such as "JAN"

Tags: sql, string, google-bigquery, timestamp

My query works fine, and will output the month as "2021-06-01 00:00:00 UTC" How can I change this query to output the month as a string value, such as "JAN" instead?

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(distinct ride_id) as total_rides,
    rideable_type,
    member_type,
    TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(started_at, month) AS month,
 FROM `data.table`
 GROUP BY    rideable_type,
             member_type,
             month;
```

Comment: isnt it june with this format

Answer (score 0):

```
UPPER(MONTHNAME("2021-06-01 00:00:00 UTC"))
--will give JUNE
```

so you'll need to wrap the value you get `UPPER(MONTHNAME(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(started_at, month)))`

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a try. And yes, I used a June date and "Jan" as an example. The query will give me results for each month, so I just grabbed one at random. Thanks for the heads up on that! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
format_timestamp('%Y-%b', started_at)
```

Example:

```
select format_timestamp('%Y-%b', current_timestamp())
```

outputs

[image]

If yo need month only - use

```
format_timestamp('%b', started_at)
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! I will give this a try. Cheers!